# anyobject does not have a membered named objectforkey in SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsnotifications

I am trying to get the `objectForKey` from a notifaction, although I am getting the error: `anyobject does not have a membered named objectforkey`

The code I am using is:

```
func executeAlbum(notification:NSNotification){
        let data = notification.userInfo.objectForKey("data") as [AlbumModel] // ERROR HERE
        self.sources = data
        self.albumTable?.reloadData()
    }
```

Can anybody tell me why it won't work and what the equivalent is?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

objectForKey method is a method of `NSDictionary` and in your case `notification.userInfo` return `[NSObject : AnyObject]?` which type is Dictionary. To get object from "swift dictionary" you will need to use its subscript method, so:

```
func executeAlbum(notification:NSNotification){
        let data:[AlbumModel]? = notification.userInfo?["data"] as? [AlbumModel] // ERROR HERE -> Not anymore
        self.sources = data
        self.albumTable?.reloadData()
    }
```

should do the work

Answer (score 0):

Your `notification.userInfo` is of type `AnyObject`. And therefore you can't use `objectForKey("")` because AnyObject does not provide this method. You might need to cast `notification.userInfo` but i don't know what is behind that.

Comment: `notification.userInfo` is type of  `[NSObject : AnyObject]?`